# Why is this Server side script not getting the Spreadsheet values?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

Server side Script

```
function getSpreadsheetValues(){
   return SpreadsheetApp.openById('1b3OWfUb3d0jy0DhxJzTYEHen- 
FHhD7nECF5NCgSDHiM').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

Client side Script

```
function readData(result){
// put the values in cells array
   var cells=[];
   cells=result;
  alert(“cell values=“+cells);// 'cell values= undefined'
}
function fail(error){
alert('Sheet not read' + error.message);
}
function getData() {
 google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(readData())
  .withFailureHandler(fail()) 
  .getSpreadsheetValues();
}
getData();
```

The `readData` function is fired, so the `getSpreadsheetValues()` didn't report an error, but the "cells" are undefined.
The Spreadsheet is "sheets" format and has 6 rows and 3 column of string data.

Comment: Try to use just `readData` instead of `readData()`, the same goes for `fail()`.

Comment: I think your problem is that in your function getData() inside the successhandler, you are actually not passing the result from the server function to the readData function. You probably need change this to `.withSuccessHandler(readData(result))`. Also, when you are calling `getData()` at the end of your client script is that supposed to execute the function, and does it actually execute the function?

Comment: Titus’ suggestion worked.. Yes Markus, the lone getData() Was meant to execute the function. Thanks to both of you. I am certain I’ll be bake for more help.